# Android Studio: How can I create an EditText field in the java code and not the xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

I am working on a project in which the user enters a list of information and I want to make it nice for the user so when they enter each point in the list, it is a new EditText box that is created visible. Essentially the flow will be type one point in the top box, as they do this another box is created right below. They they can keep repeating this process with as many points as they want, or they can submit the data at the bottom with a button.

Rather than making many EditText boxes in the xml and setting them invisible until the box above them is filled, can I make a method in my java file that creates the edittext box when the circumstances arise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(context);
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WARP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
myLayout.addView(myEditText);
```

you can do something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by myLayout? What should replace that. Thanks.

Comment: Say you have a RelativeLayout in your activity.// RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); // this is your myLayout